# i can't take message from Apollo MQ.

Tags: java

when i connect Apollo MQ i am getting connection as true. but if i try to fetch messages from the queue i am getting message as null.

my connection code is

ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(uName, pass, asBroker);

```
    connection = factory.createConnection();      
    connection.start();
    session = connection.createSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    brokerConnected = true;
```

code for receiving message from queue

public Syncable receive(String queue) throws ActiveSyncMQException {

```
    ObjectMessage message = null;
    Syncable syncPojo = null;
    try{
        Destination destination = session.createQueue(queue);
        MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);
        message = (ObjectMessage) consumer.receive(10000);
        syncPojo = (Syncable) message.getObject();
    }catch(JMSException jmsEx){
        throw new ActiveSyncMQException("JMS exception while receiving message from queue("+queue+")", jmsEx);
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        throw new ActiveSyncMQException("Exception while receiving message from queue("+queue+")", ex);
    }
    return syncPojo;
}
```

Comment: Are there message on your queue? Check queue name where your producer produces and where you are consuming. Check broker where producer is producing and where you are consuming.

Comment: tried seeing what you get in your message object?

Comment: The queue having  messages.queue name is correct. In UI of apollo MQ i can see the thread  is consuming. but it is not picking the messages.